# multiplication of ordered pairs

Tags: complex-numbers

From what I've seen, ordered pair multiplication is $(a,b) \times (c,d) = (ac-bd,ad+bc)$.

Also, $(0,1)$ represents $i$. So if I wanted to take $(0,-1) \times (0.-1)$, that would be $= (-1,0)$, right?

Which means $-i^2 = -1$.  But $-i^2 = 1$!  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're failing to distinguish between $(-i)^2$ and $-(i^2)$. The former is $-1$ (it always holds that $(-a)^2=a^2$ in a ring); the latter is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking symbols wrong. It should be $(-\iota)^2$ and $-(\iota)^2$.

Comment: why are you using `\iota` for the complex $i$ ?

Comment: @zwim- Its iota which represents complex i not i.